# Direcionamentos inexistentes no servidor

Tags: wordpress, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url

Tenho o site de um cliente rodando no cPanel e foi desenvolvido uma nova versão (antes 2013, agora 2014) com todo sistema diferente.
Foi utilizado Wordpress para montar o site, e o anterior foi "deletado(zipado)" do servidor, porém quando se digita **www**.sitedocliente.com.br entra na "versão 2013" que não esta mais na pasta 'public_html' e quando se digita http://sitedocliente.com.br (sem o www) cai na "versão 2014". Verifiquei os redirecionamentos e não há nenhum, possuem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Sim, estão no mesmo servidor

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância, mas onde localizo estas configurações?

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o WordPress salva o endereço do site no banco de dados.

É possível arrumar isso direto no banco alterando os campos `siteurl` e `home` para o novo endereço na tabela `wp_options` (note que o prefixo `wp_` pode variar com a sua instalação).

Não tem problema caso você não tenha acesso ao banco de dados ou por algum motivo não saiba como fazer, pois é possível também corrigir isso pelo arquivo `wp-config.php` adicionando o seguinte código a baixo da linha `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`:

```php
update_option('siteurl', 'URL_DO_SITE' );
update_option('home', 'URL_DO_SITE' );
```

Feito isso, basta acessar o site uma vez e remover estas duas linhas (remova elas, caso o contrário isso será alterado no banco de dados toda vez que o site for aberto).

Também existe outra alternativa para isso, no caso é sobrescrever o que esta salvo no banco de dados usando o `wp-config.php`, configurado as definições `WP_SITEURL` e `WP_HOME`.

No caso pode adicionar desta forma antes do comentário:

```php
/* Isto é tudo, pode parar de editar! :) */
```

Como por exemplo:

```php
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'URL_DO_SITE' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'URL_DO_SITE' );
```

Referências:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress
http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29
http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Blog_address_.28URL.29